# Horizontal scroll by wheel/swipe on fullpage.js - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, horizontal-scrolling, wordpress-gutenberg, touchpad

i've got the fullpage.js for wordpress and want to scroll horizontally with the touchpad. I already found this code as solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32934314/13353737

Can somebody explain how to add the code in the existing codes from mcw-fullpage-gutenberg?

Comment: What do you mean by "existing codes"? Please be more specific about where exactly you want to add this solution.

Comment: fullPage 3.0.7/ https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js of this javascript